# How to select this inner json data list

Tags: json, flutter, dart

i have dummy json and i want to target the inner list and return several widget with that list data. The data i want to get is 'content', for example i want to return a few cards with 'content' data,

```
Card 1 = 'Full Name'

Card 2 = 'Email Address' 

Card 3 = 'Phone Number'
```

my widget code

```
for (var i = 0; i < formPages[index + 1]['content'].length; i++) 
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 20, 24, 0),
                color: Colors.grey,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 30,
                child: Text(
                    formPages[index + 1]['content'][0]['question']),
              ),
```

dummy json

```
{
      'page': 2,
      'part': 1,
      'title': 'General Information',
      'content': [
        {
          'question_type': 'text_box',
          'question': 'Full Name',
          'option': [],
        },
        {
          'question_type': 'text_box',
          'question': 'Email Address',
          'option': [],
        },
        {
          'question_type': 'text_box',
          'question': 'Phone Number',
          'option': [],
        },
      ]
    }
```

Comment: you should use  like `Text(formPages[index + 1]['content'][i ]['question']),` in loop

Comment: can you write it in my code ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < formPages[index + 1]['content'].length; i++) 
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 20, 24, 0),
            color: Colors.grey,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 30,
            child: Text(
                formPages[index + 1]['content']['question'][i]),
          ),
```